# SharePoint Online Search RefinementFilters with combination of and & or operator

Tags: search, sharepoint-online

I am struggeling with refinementFilters in a SharePoint-Online Search.
From the specs, I cannot see how to combine and & or operator to get my results.

The requirement is to show all news from a given date range and a specific company, as also these news from the same date range but with a mandatory flag.

Following Refinement Filter is working and I get the news from a certain company of the given date range:

and(**owstaxIdGesellschaft**:59a24508-cbb1-4149-83ed-fda83136be6e,**FirstPublishedDate**:range(2021-01-01T23:00:00.000Z,2021-12-15T15:58:00.408Z))

Now I want to get also those news with the mandatory flag of the same date range and I do not know how to combine this into the previous mentioned filter.

I tried with the following but with no avail:

and(**owstaxIdGesellschaft**:59a24508-cbb1-4149-83ed-fda83136be6e,**FirstPublishedDate**:range(2021-01-31T23:00:00.000Z,2021-12-15T15:58:00.408Z)) **or** (and(**owstaxIdVerpflichtend**:396fd210-ed3c-423e-a6fd-8d2ec90a3cb7,**FirstPublishedDate**:range(2021-01-31T23:00:00.000Z,2021-12-15T15:58:00.408Z)))

This returns no results.

Query Template: FileExtension:aspx IsDocument:true PromotedState:2
Refiners: owstaxIdGesellschaft,FirstPublishedDate,owstaxIdVerpflichtend

Any Idea how to combine and & or?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found it.
The solution is to have the or in the first place.

**or**(and(**owstaxIdGesellschaft**:59a24508-cbb1-4149-83ed-fda83136be6e,**FirstPublishedDate**:range(2021-01-01T23:00:00.000Z,2021-12-15T15:58:00.408Z)),and(**owstaxIdVerpflichtend**:396fd210-ed3c-423e-a6fd-8d2ec90a3cb7,**FirstPublishedDate**:range(2021-01-01T23:00:00.000Z,2021-12-15T15:58:00.408Z)))

With this query, I now get what I want.: All news from the given date range and the given company, as also these news with the mandatory flag (owstaxIdVerpflichtend) to yes from the same date range.

From the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/fast-query-language-fql-syntax-reference#or), this wasn't clear to me.

May be this helps others, Ronny